# how to change the values in a combobox dynamically in Ruby Tk

Tags: ruby, combobox, refresh, tk-toolkit

The idea is quite simple: I have 2 comboboxes. The second one should refreseh its values depending on the chose from the first one.

```
# combobox 1:
$shape = TkVariable.new
$combobox_1 = Tk::Tile::Combobox.new(parent) { textvariable $shape; values ['IPE', 'HEA']}

# combobox 2:
$size = TkVariable.new
$combobox_2 = Tk::Tile::Combobox.new(parent) { textvariable $size; values $size_list}

# action
$combobox_1.bind("<ComboboxSelected>") {
  case $shape
  when 'IPE' then $size_list = [80, 100, ...]
  when 'HEA' then $size_list = [90, 130, ...]
  end
  }
```

But nothing happens. combobox 2 doesn't seem to realize that its values have been changed. how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, you used this variable to create the combo box, but changing it will not change the combobox.

I suppose what you are looking for is [set](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/f/ffi-tk-2010.08.23/Tk/Tile/ComboBox.html#method-i-set)

```
when 'IPE' then $combobox_2.values([80, 100, ...])
```

Comment: `set` seems to put all values in a single row but doesn't create a list. Just of curiosity I switched `set` with `values` and got a refreshed list! Thanks for your leading advice.

Comment: @ericMTR thanks for poiting out, correct my answer for further reference